# What is the default value for an unset variant in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I am working with some old code and it defines a global variable like this...

```
Public myvar
```

This variable is never assigned a value, but is later used in a test...

```
If myvar <> somevalue then
    'do something
End If
```

For what values of somevalue would that something be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The default value is `Empty`.
- "Something will be done" for any value except `Empty`, `0` or `""`...

  - ... for the value Nothing, the code will raise an error and "something will not be done".

From the [VB6 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243352%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

> When variables are initialized, a
>   numeric variable is initialized to 0,
>   a variable-length string is
>   initialized to a zero-length string
>   (""), and a fixed-length string is
>   filled with zeros. Variant variables
>   are initialized to Empty. Each element
>   of a user-defined type variable is
>   initialized as if it were a separate
>   variable.

Comment: If memory serves, the code above will crash if `someValue` is assigned a value of `Nothing`, or is an object whose default property yields `Nothing`, etc. since the not-equals operator would compare notice that the type of `someValue` is `Object`, try to fetch its default property, and then try to compare that (fetching <i>its</i> default property if need be, etc.)  Since trying to get the default property of `Nothing` will fail, the code will crash.

Comment: @supercat question says "This variable is never assigned a value". Therefore since this is VB6 it will contain Empty (different from Nothing). Therefore "Something will be done" for any somevalue except Empty, 0 or ""

Comment: The question presupposes that `myVar` is never assigned a value and asks for what values of `someValue` the indicated statement will execute.  I'm not sure what will happen if `On Error Resume Next` is in effect, but if it isn't I'm pretty certain that the `do something` code will not execute when `someValue` is `Nothing`.

Comment: Oh! Now I've read your first comment properly. Yes, you are probably right. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

From [Get the most out of Variants in VB6](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/get-the-most-out-of-variants-in-vb6/) I would make an assumption that if `myvar` is not "" then `do something`. I am not sure and can't check it right now but you can check it yourself.

> When a Variant has been declared but
>   not assigned a value, it contains the
>   special value Empty. You can test for
>   this with the IsEmpty function
>   ...
>   
> If
>   an empty Variant is used in an
>   expression, it will evaluate as either
>   the value 0 or an empty string
>   depending on the expression.

Comment: +1 for the reminder that an Empty variant will be coerced to a string as `""` or a number as `0`