# In VB6, do declared fields have default values?

Tags: vb6

I am going through some old VB6 code and in many forms, I encounter declaration statements like -

```
 PEC_NUM_ENT(1) As Byte
 EC_MORE_RW_EXIST(0) As Byte
 EC_CODE_IND(0) As Byte
 EC_DATA(7) As PRXDetail
```

My question is, do these fields have default values? If so, what are the values? Thanks.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284216  (not a duplicate)

Comment: The idea of calling variables "fields" in VB is a little... odd.

Comment: @BobRiemersma Do fields only refer to those "variables"  that belong to classes?

Comment: @BobRiemersma  Variables aren't called fields; the "fields" here are the components of a user-defined type--just like the fields of a struct in C.

Comment: Ok, but in a UDT these are called "elements."  See the manual. However at least the term "field" makes more sense in such a context.  And no, properties of a class are properties not fields.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.  Numerical and date types default to 0, strings to an empty string (i.e., ""), boolean to False, and variant to EMPTY.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is EMPTY like "null" in Java. In this case will EC_DATA be EMPTY initially?

Comment: Empty is not the same as null.  As I recall, a variant is basically an untyped typed until it is used--so if it used first as a string, then Empty is "", etc.  I kind of missed EC_DATA, which is an array of PRXDetail--apparently a user-defined type.  I am not sure, but suspect that each field in the UDT would have the default values.  I am unsure how VB6 handles UDT under the hood, but I suspect each element of the array is a memory location.  The values would be obtained by EC_DATA(0).FieldName and so forth.

Comment: +1 Yes, If an empty Variant is used in an expression, it will evaluate as either the value 0 or an empty string depending on the expression.

Answer (score 8):

From the [VB6 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243352(v=VS.60).aspx)

> When variables are initialized, a
> numeric variable is initialized to 0,
> a variable-length string is
> initialized to a zero-length string
> (""), and a fixed-length string is
> filled with zeros. Variant variables
> are initialized to Empty. Each element
> of a user-defined type variable is
> initialized as if it were a separate
> variable.

PRXDETAIL looks like it might be a user-defined type