# Do VB6 declarations work like Arrays?

Tags: vb6

I am new to VB. I am reading some VB6 code and I come across declaration statements like

```
  PQR_SSN(8) As Byte // this probably refers to social security number
  TR_DATA(7) As TransactionDetail
```

In another file, TransactionDetial is defined

```
  Public Type TransactionDetail
  A(0) As Byte  
  B(0) As Byte
  Comment(40) As Byte
  //... etc
  //...
  End Type
```

Does TR_DATA(7) mean that it is an "array" that can store 8 instances of TransactionDetail?

Also, Consider Comment(40). Can I access individual bytes of the comment like this -

```
  Comment(3)
```

Also, suppose that I do not assign all 41 bytes to Comment. Then will the rest of the bytes contain garbage values?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Data declared as Byte, even arrays, has an initial value of zero (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TR_DATA(7) is an array of 8 elements of type TransactionDetail.

Yes, the Comments array can be accessed through individual elements as you show.

Unassigned elements *may* contain garbage values - I wouldn't trust them - but I can't recall whether VB helpfully pre-initialises variables.  I would expect it would, just to be helpful to users, and that it would initialise numeric variables to 0, fixed-length strings to all zeros, and objects to Empty.

Found [this web link](http://www.1sayfa.com/1024/diger/vb/ch11.htm) which gives some useful guidance on arrays in VB6.

Also just found this: [VB6 Variable Scope](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-variable-scope); which says:

> Unlike many other languages, VB does not allow you to initialize
>   variables; this must be done with an executable statement. However,
>   each variable does have a default initialization value. Numeric
>   variable types are initialized to zero, Strings are initialized to "",
>   Booleans are initialized to False, etc.

Comment: The lower bound in VB6 may be 0 or 1 (it's usually 0) but can be changed with the OPTION BASE statement.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: VB6 does [initialise values to 0/""](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10045297/588306).

Answer (score 0):

@Nick: yes, VB helpfully does exactly as you surmise.

@CodeBlue: your last question suggests that you may want to investigate dynamic arrays. If so, I would suggest that you investigate in particular the Redim and Preserve statements.