# Multiple variable assignments in one statement in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6, variable-assignment

Working with legacy code I came across some strange variable assignments that I am not sure are legal VB6 syntax, but I cannot find the documentation to back up the feeling.

```
Dim ComStart, ComEnd, CR As Boolean
ComStart = ComEnd = CR = False
```

My suspicions are

a) the original declarations should be

`Dim ComStart as Boolean, ComEnd as Boolean, CR as Boolean`

b) the declarations as they are implemented now will not assign anything to `ComStart`.

Any answers or documentation are much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you have found is technically *legal* VB6, because it compiles and runs. But it is very likely that the original author thought the code would do something different! There are two misunderstandings.

- `ComStart` and `ComEnd` and `CR` are variants, not Booleans.
- In VB6 `=` is the equality operator, not the assignment operator found in C.

  - `CR = False` does not change the value of `CR`. It compares the current value of `CR` to `False`, and evaluates as `True` if `CR` is equal to `False`. Let's say it evaluates as `False`
  - Now you have the expression `ComEnd = False`. Again, this does not change the value of `ComEnd`. It compares it with `False`, and evaluates as `True` if `ComEnd` is equal to `False`. This time let's say it evaluates as `True`.
  - Now you have the *assignment statement* `ComStart = True`. This sets the value of `ComStart` to `True`

So your original code

```
Dim ComStart, ComEnd, CR As Boolean
ComStart = ComEnd = CR = False
```

Creates two variants `ComStart` and `ComEnd` and a Boolean `CR`, and then

- `CR` keeps its default value, `False`
- `ComEnd` keeps its [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284216/what-is-the-default-value-for-an-unset-variant-in-vb6), `Empty`
- `ComStart` is set to `False` because `Empty = (Empty = False)` is `False`.

Simple! ... I hope the rest of the legacy code is less, well, *accidental*.

Comment: +1 for an informative and helpful answer! This is just one of those jobs that takes all the fun out of being right because I now have to re-evaluate everything using these variables and try to guess what the author thought was happening vs. what is really going on. Your sentiment is welcomed, but rest assured that I will be back to SO several more times before this project is over -_-

Answer (score 1):

So the code should be, as you guessed:

```
Dim ComStart as Boolean, ComEnd as Boolean, CR as Boolean
```

That's a common mistake on VB6 developers with little or no experience, or .NET developers working on VB6 code :). It works, because VB6 would assume the value assigned and would cast it automatically, but it can also cause nasty bugs really hard to debug.