# How to compute the duration of time using two DTPicker by hour

Tags: vb6

How to compute the duration of time in and time out using 4 DTPicker

```
 Dim d1, d2, d3  As Date
 Dim d4 As Integer
 Dim x As Long
```

Option Explicit

```
  Private Sub Command1_Click()
  d1 = DTPicker1.Value + TimePicker.Value
  d2 = DTPicker2.Value + TimePicker2.Value

  x = DateDiff("h", d1, d2)



   MsgBox x



  End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
TimePicker.Format = dtpTime
TimePicker2.Format = dtpTime
```

End Sub

========================================================================[see attached image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QA20.png)

I expect the output of 7:00 AM - 3:00 PM = 8hrs, when I add more days the actual output is 32 hrs in 2 days, it should be 16hrs

Comment: What exact values you have in d1 and d2?

Comment: the exact values of d1 and d2 is the combination of time and date .
DTPicker1 is date Timpicker is time
DTPicker2 is date Timpicker2 is time

Comment: The DateDiff returns the total number of hours difference between two dates. It is clear that 7AM today is 32 hours behind 3PM tomorrow. (24+8) hours.

Comment: You should first get the difference between 7AM and 3PM with same date. That will give you 8 hours. Then you should get the difference between two dates in days. And then multiply the days with the hours (8). That will give you 16 hours as you expected.

Comment: Can you please give me an example code sir?

Comment: I don't have the example code... I explained you the logic..you need to  Try writing code as per the logic and it will give you expected output. If you face any problem wiring in code, you can ask question here.

Comment: Not the answer, but a side note: Dim d1, d2, d3  As Date will declare d1 and d2 as variant, only d3 is really a Date. See on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012230/multiple-variable-assignments-in-one-statement-in-visual-basic-6

Comment: You can display both time and date in same DTPicker with CustomFormat M/d/yyyy hh:mm. Then using DateDiff is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the start and end times are in the same day, this should work:

```
Dim hoursPerDay As Integer
Dim days As Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    hoursPerDay = DateDiff("h", TimePicker1.Value, TimePicker2.Value)
    days = DateDiff("d", DTPicker1.Value, DTPicker2.Value)

    MsgBox hoursPerDay * days

End Sub
```

Otherwise, check if `hoursPerDay` is negative:

```
If hoursPerDay < 0 Then hoursPerDay = hoursPerDay + 24
```